# create telerik side drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, xamarin, telerik

I am trying to create telerik side drawer i am new to android development can you please explain with some example to create.

Comment: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/sidedrawer/sidedrawer-getting-started

Comment: I am Using this link http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/android/controls/sidedrawer/sidedrawer-features but they are not specified XML code to generate controle

Comment: They show the `xaml` used to create the file in that doc at the `Example` section @ http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/xamarin/controls/sidedrawer/sidedrawer-getting-started#example

Comment: he is asking for axml, not xaml (I think)

Comment: Yes @Json I need axml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [sample](https://github.com/telerik/Android-samples/blob/master/Samples-Xamarin/Resources/layout/fragment_side_drawer_features.axml) axml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.telerik.android.primitives.widget.sidedrawer.RadSideDrawer
        android:id="@+id/sideDrawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.telerik.com/forums/not-able-to-setup-radsidedrawer igot it answer from this url they are explained clearly.